# Функции пользователей

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть массив в котором все элементы ровны 2, 3,4 або 5. Нужно так чтобы 2 заменялось на 5, 3 на 4....Я это решил делать через if но столкнулся с проблемой и не могу вывести уже отформатированный массив из ifов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

void function(int m[5][5], int i, int j)
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        cout << m[i][j] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (m[i][j] == 2)
        {
            m[i][j] = 5;
        }
        if (m[i][j] == 3)
        {
            m[i][j] = 4;
        }
        if (m[i][j] == 4)
        {
            m[i][j] = 3;
        }
        if (m[i][j] == 5)
        {
            m[i][j] = 2;
        }

    }
} cout << m[i][j] << " ";
     cout << "\n";

      }
     int main(){
int p;
int arr[5][5];
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 5;
        }
}
    function(arr, 5, 5);
    cout << "\n Повторити програму? \n1. - так \n2.-ні\n";
    cin >> p;

} while (p == 1);
```

}

Comment: `switch` поможет

Comment: для вывода разве это не одно и то самое будет?

Comment: у вас ошибка двойной смены значения. в команде `switch` есть ещё `break` , чтобу вашу ошибку исправить.

Comment: Добавьте `else` после всех if-ов кроме последнего, ведь если элемент уже был обработан, то второй раз проверять его не нужно

Comment: Только 2..5? Тогда почему у вас `arr[i][j] = rand() % 5;`? Т.е. элементы 0..4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас реально условие, что все элементы — 2, 3, 4 или 5, и категорически надо выводить в функции, а не после нее, то я бы делал так:

```
void func(int a[5][5])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout << setw(3) << (a[i][j] = 7 - a[i][j]);
        cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int arr[5][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout << setw(3) << (arr[i][j] = rand()%4+2);
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n";

    func(arr);

    cout << "\n\n\n";


    // Чтоб убедиться
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

См. https://ideone.com/7uhZsT